# Always get read timeout

Tags: c++, libserial

I'm currently trying to make the PIC32UBL Qt/Linux/Mac port working by serial port. So far I always get timeouts while reading the serial port.

Here is the full [PIC32UBL-qt](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pic32ubl-qt/) open source project.

I'm using `/dev/ttyUSB0` as serial port, this adapter was tested. Also I verified that target circuit is receiving / sending data to the host program (PIC32UBL-qt) with a logic analyser. Also it is fully working with the Windows version of the PIC32UBL.

The defective part is at `comport.cpp:156`

```
unsigned short CComPort::ReadComPort(char* buffer, int MaxLen)
{
  if (serialPort != NULL)
  {
    SerialPort::DataBuffer dataBuffer;

    // Added a catch for timeouts
    try
    {
      serialPort->Read(dataBuffer, MaxLen,10);

      std::copy(dataBuffer.begin(), dataBuffer.end(), buffer);
    }
    catch(std::exception &e)
    {

    }

    return dataBuffer.size();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So the `Read` always throws a timeout, tried different timing (100, 1000) : always timeout, and also tried infinite (0) : never get out.

Could the issue be related that the `libserial` is working with signal handler and I'm using a serial / usb FTDI adapter?

Comment: 1) What about trying to read only 1 byte?  (What is `maxlen`)  2) Confident data is receiving data of the correct baud, stop bits, etc?  By looping back this port's output data as its own input, that potential difference can be eliminated.

Comment: @chux Thanks for your pointer, changed for reading one byte at a time and it's working perfectly, will post the answer including working code version for this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By chux's comment, I tested by reading only one character at a time and it's working perfectly, here is the final version of the method in the program :

```
unsigned short CComPort::ReadComPort(char* buffer, int MaxLen)
{
  if (serialPort != NULL)
  {
    int nCount = 0;

    while(serialPort->IsDataAvailable() && nCount < MaxLen)
    {
      buffer[nCount++] = serialPort->ReadByte(10);
    }

    return nCount;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Glad this "works" for you, yet it may be highly inefficient.  It appears code does not really ever want to wait - return if data is not available _now_.  To improve efficiency, consider using a command to inquiry how many bytes are available to get more than one at a time.

Comment: @chux Well the `Read` function wasn't working (for some reason) and this code is not very inefficient because it will loop until no characters available or `MaxLen` reached...

Comment: I suspect `Read()` was "working".  It is just that you asked for `MaxLen` bytes and less than `MaxLen` bytes were available, so it waits, and waits....  IAC, Suggest reviewing this solution later on.